# Compute the sum of sum of sum of digits of $1976^{1976}$

Tags: number-theory, summation, algebraic-number-theory

I have this problem:

Compute $ sd(sd(sd(1976^{1976}))) $, where $sd()$ represents the sum of digits.

---

I know that $1976 = 2^3 \cdot 19 \cdot 13$, so we have to compute $ sd(sd(sd((2^3 \cdot 19 \cdot 13)^{1976}))) $.

I also know that $sd(a\cdot b) = sd(sd(a)\cdot sd(b))$, so I can rewrite the above as: $sd(sd(sd( sd(2^{3\cdot1976}) \cdot sd(13^{1976}) \cdot sd(19^{1976})))$ but I think this is not the right direction.

I also know that $sd(m\cdot n) \leq sd(m)\cdot sd(n)$, so theoretically I should be able, maybe, to approximate the sum, but h**ow to compute the sum of sum of sum of digits of that number ($1976^{1976})$?**

Thank you very much!

*Note: I previously [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2966113/compute-the-sum-of-digits-of-an-exponential) how to compute $sd(1976^{1976})$ but it seems there was a typo in my book and the real question is the question I ask here. I edited the old question, to the iterative sum and accepted the correct answer.*

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I do think the problem is slightly different.

Comment: According to WA the sum of digits of $1976^{1976}$ is $29239$ and the sum of digits of that is (obviously) $25$ so the next one up is $7$.  This suggests:  try to prove that your value is just the iterated sum of digits.

Comment: sd(a⋅b)=sd(sd(a)⋅sd(b)) is stated<br>What if a=b=19?
Then sd(a⋅b)=sd(361)=10 but sd(sd(a)⋅sd(b))=sd(10⋅10)=sd(100)=1 so the two are not equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to see that the iterated sum of digits of your expression is $7$, thus your answer must be congruent to $ 7 \pmod 9$.

To solve the given problem:

Note that $$\log_{10}{1976^{1976}}\approx 6512.474994$$ so your expression has  $6513$ digits.  Thus the sum of digits of your expression is not greater than $$9\times 6513=58617$$

Now, that has $5$ digits so the second sum of digits is less than $9\times 5=45$.  Now, inspection quickly shows that there is no number $≤45$ which has a sum of digits greater than $12$.  Thus the answer to your question is also $7$.

Comment: Thank you very very much!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate $1976^{1976}\mod {9}$. Be decomposing $1976$ as you did we have $$1976^{1976}=(2^3.19.13)^{1976}=(4.19.26)^{1976}$$as we know $$26\cong -1\mod 9\\19\cong 1\mod 9$$therefore$$1976^{1976}\cong 2^{2\times 1976}\mod 9\cong 2^{2\times 1974}\cdot 16\cong 7\mod 9$$so the sum of the digits after too many levels is $7$